# algorithm to find hidden phrase in string

Tags: string, algorithm, search

I am looking for an algorithm to solve a particular type of puzzle. Given an input string and a list of character counts for the hidden phrase words, I want to find the list of possible phrases hidden inside. The characters composing the phrase occur in order in the string, but random extra characters are sometimes inserted in between. An example:

puzzle string:

```
typacnmlllrspoanrjaoadiisrleeairebsdrqletsaormelomtuapkeerfsrhlwcoipmaycarwacyhrsolneoaieeeteibtuillllndepwctstravelebotseibubblensooysadosnickershwdctgmixturesasonogidropsyggnlpaugoumugpawelaecgbarrynitkymmezhmtsffoljmsnsxbw
```

hidden phrase character counts:

```
_ _ _  _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _  _ _  _ _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _   _ _   _   _ _ _
```

And the correct hidden phrase for this input is:

```
all roads lead to rome was not built in a day
```

There will probably be multiple matching phrases; I can then narrow down the search space and further refine the results with a secondary algorithm or manually.

Comment: The algorithm depends on the rules for solving the puzzles. In most puzzles, the goal is to *find* the algorithm. Do you know how to solve the puzzle? There will be no general algorithm for solving all puzzles.

Comment: I think you'll need to pair this with a dictionary of known English words - otherwise the number of potential phrases will be enormous even for a moderately long puzzle string.

Comment: Ant P, this class of puzzles have the same rules. A phrase is obfuscated with extra characters added between the characters of the phrase. The clue is the the given word/character counts.

Comment: 500, yes a dictionary will probably be necessary, but it must also be flexible enough to allow for proper nouns not found in the dictionary.

Comment: After much searching, I found something that generates these types of puzzles: [word search with a hidden message](http://puzzlemaker.discoveryeducation.com/WordSearchWithMessageSetupForm.html)

Comment: If all your words are found in the dictionary, the problem is hard enough. If you can have words NOT found in the dictionary too, umm... good luck. Every answer with the correct number of words and letters becomes a solution.

Comment: I think the word search you linked to produces a gird where you can find words horizontally, vertically and diagonally and where the remaining letters spell a message. Anyway, generating such puzzles is easy. In your case, the remaining letters don't spell anything (except trouble) and there are long stretches of characters between the letters of your phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach to this problem is to find the first word that you can find with the requisite number of letters (by first word I mean that ends earliest) for each word. For example, the first word you want is three letters - and in `TYPACMLL` the first three letter word you can find is `PAL`. We know that if there exists a solution, there must exist a solution that starts with `PAL`. This is because, if there exists another solution (such as the one that starts with `ALL ROADS LEAD`) with a word that ends later, then we can simply use the solution from that and apply it to `PAL`: `PAL ROADS LEAD`.

So now you just have to devise an algorithm to find the first word of length `n` in a string. This can be done `O(N^2 * C)` in a very brute-force way:

```
for l in string:
    for word in dictionary that has k letters and starts with l:
        if word exists in string:
            store word
            store end_pos
```

This admittedly has a large constant factor, `C`, of number of length k words in dictionary that start with letter l, but at least thats not dependent on the length of your string. Of course you can do some optimizations here, like trim of characters from the end of your string because you know that there must be at least enough characters to match the rest of your secret pattern, or have some heuristic of early termination and guessing - repeating if necessary.

The next step would be to repeat this process, using the substring beginning at the letter at the end of the word you just found with the smallest end_pos. The total runtime for the algorithm is therefore `O(N^3)` because you have to use that algorithm `N` times at most.

Hope this is what your looking for - I may have misinterpreted the question.

**Note**

This style of algorithm is called *greedy* algorithm which utilizes the exchange principle: the result given by the greedy algorithm is no worse than the optimal solution at any point in time. For more information on this (the exchange argument) you can see: [this paper](http://www.idi.ntnu.no/~mlh/algkon/greedy.pdf) section 4.2